# How to create two XML files from one XML files in python

Tags: python, xml, file

I have this XML file

```
<Source>
    <segment1>
        <userRefNumber>test1</userRefNumber>
        <subscriber>
            <industryCode>ZZZZZ</industryCode>
            <memberCode>12345</memberCode>
            <inquirySubscriberPrefixCode>0622</inquirySubscriberPrefixCode>
        </subscriber>
        <options>
            <country>us</country>
            <language>en</language>
        </options>
        <tracking>
            <transactionTimeStamp>2021-02-25T04:09:30.508-06:00</transactionTimeStamp>
        </tracking>
    </segment1>
    <example2>
        <subscriber>
            <industryCode>ZAAAA</industryCode>
            <memberCode>999999</memberCode>
            <inquirySubscriberPrefixCode>0622</inquirySubscriberPrefixCode>
        </subscriber>
        <options>
            <country>us</country>
            <language>en</language>
        </options>
        <tracking>
            <transactionTimeStamp>2020-02-25T04:09:30.508-06:00</transactionTimeStamp>
        </tracking>
    </example2>
</Source>
```

I'd like to create, through Python, two XML files, that is one for each child:

- one xml file for segment1
- one xml file for segment2

xml1 should look like this:

```
<Source>
    <segment1>
        <userRefNumber>test1</userRefNumber>
        <subscriber>
            <industryCode>ZZZZZ</industryCode>
            <memberCode>12345</memberCode>
            <inquirySubscriberPrefixCode>0622</inquirySubscriberPrefixCode>
        </subscriber>
        <options>
            <country>us</country>
            <language>en</language>
        </options>
        <tracking>
            <transactionTimeStamp>2021-02-25T04:09:30.508-06:00</transactionTimeStamp>
        </tracking>
    </segment1>
</Source>
```

and xml2 should look like this:

```
<Source>
    <example2>
        <subscriber>
            <industryCode>ZAAAA</industryCode>
            <memberCode>999999</memberCode>
            <inquirySubscriberPrefixCode>0622</inquirySubscriberPrefixCode>
        </subscriber>
        <options>
            <country>us</country>
            <language>en</language>
        </options>
        <tracking>
            <transactionTimeStamp>2020-02-25T04:09:30.508-06:00</transactionTimeStamp>
        </tracking>
    </example2>
</Source>
```

The splitting criteria is this: to create one separate xml file for each element. In the example above there are two elements (segment1 and example2): therefore i'd like to create two xml files for each one of those.

I have checked this answer [Split one large .xml file in more .xml files (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231220/split-one-large-xml-file-in-more-xml-files-python) but in that example the children have the same name so I guess the findall function doesn't apply to my case, as the children have different names (segment1 and segment2). Is it possible to create a single xml file based on the order of the elements from the root?

Comment: How should xm1 & xml2 look like - please update the post with the requested output.

Comment: Are you aware that in xml1 you have document & version and in xml2 not?

Comment: yes.. I don't need to write them out.

Comment: so you need them once or you dont need them **at all** ?

Comment: I don't need them at all

Comment: Explain the requested split logic in the post body.

Comment: What if `example2` will be renamed to `xyz13` ?

Comment: then I should be able to create an xml file called xyz13

Answer (score 1):

The below seems to work. The main point here is to loop over the elements and chack which one of them start with `segment`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<Source>
    <document>response</document>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <segment1>
        <userRefNumber>test1</userRefNumber>
        <subscriber>
            <industryCode>ZZZZZ</industryCode>
            <memberCode>12345</memberCode>
            <inquirySubscriberPrefixCode>0622</inquirySubscriberPrefixCode>
        </subscriber>
        <options>
            <country>us</country>
            <language>en</language>
        </options>
        <tracking>
            <transactionTimeStamp>2021-02-25T04:09:30.508-06:00</transactionTimeStamp>
        </tracking>
    </segment1>
    <segment2>
        <userRefNumber>test2</userRefNumber>
        <subscriber>
            <industryCode>ZAAAA</industryCode>
            <memberCode>999999</memberCode>
            <inquirySubscriberPrefixCode>0622</inquirySubscriberPrefixCode>
        </subscriber>
        <options>
            <country>us</country>
            <language>en</language>
        </options>
        <tracking>
            <transactionTimeStamp>2020-02-25T04:09:30.508-06:00</transactionTimeStamp>
        </tracking>
    </segment2>
</Source>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
counter = 1
for child in list(root):
    if child.tag.startswith('segment'):
        src = ET.Element('Source')
        src.append(child)
        with open(f'out_{counter}.xml','w') as f:
            tree = ET.ElementTree(src)
            tree.write(f,encoding="unicode")
        counter += 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there another option instead of startswith? for example: is there something like "contains"? In my file there will not always be "segment"

Comment: Come with a concrete example please. In general you can use : `'segment' in child.tag`

Comment: I have update the post with an example

Comment: Are you aware to 1) You have posted a new example as answer 2) You have changed the basic conditions of your original answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated the question in the original post.